# Strange issue with firewalld and ssh on Almalinux 9

Tags: linux, ssh, firewalld

I have this strange issue with firewalld and ssh on my fresh AlmaLinux 9 installation.
I changed the ssh port to a non-default port(9322), restarted the sshd daemon. Firewalld is running in it's default mode, so SSH service is active. It is loaded from /usr/lib/firewalld/services/ssh.xml. Port 22 is defined in this file.

However, without changing the firewall config to reflect the non-standard port for ssh, I am able to login on port 9322 via ssh. How is this possible ? When I change to a different-non standard port, i.e. 9522, restart ssh, the same happens. I have access via ssh on port 9522 without modifying the firewall config. How is that possible ? I must be overlooking something but can't figure out what. Anyone who can shed a light on this ?

Comment: That depends a bit on how and what you're testing, i.e. connecting  from the system itself will usually result in a access being granted, without changing firewall rules, where remote connections can as expected  still be denied. Normally `firewall-cmd --add-port=<NewPort>/tcp --permanent`  and 
`firewall-cmd --reload` would indeed be a required action IMHO

Comment: I connect to the server from my homebox via Termius, an ssh-client.  I changed  the settings via the remote console of the server. What I did exactl(From the console): Change the port for ssh in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Changed it from the default 22 to 9322. Saved the file and restarted sshd daemon. There where no open ssh connections at that time. netstat shows that ssh is listening on port 9322. So, without changing the firewalld config, which still was supposed to open port 22 for ssh (as the ssh-service was enabled in it's config, not the port) I was able to connect with ssh to port 9322.

Comment: You are stating facts and conclusions difficult to verify. There's also the possibility that the firewall isn't firewalling at all for your case. You'd have to provide the firewalld setup, like in /etc/firewalld/ relevant parts of firewalld.conf, services/ zones/ etc. There would also be the low level nftables result (typically `nft list table inet firewalld`) but it's verbose and difficult to interpret.

Comment: Well, the issue wasn't in the firewall config at all after all. For whatever reason, the SSH client I used (Termius)  seems  to be the culprit. When I tried to use the default terminal from my ubuntu laptop towards the server, the firewall performed as expected.

Comment: If a server's firewall can be circumvented by a client, then "the firewall isn't firewalling at all for your case".